# Virtual guest does not have network access in cafe

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox

My Virtualbox guest OS (Ubuntu on ubuntu host) does not connect to the internet when I have wifi access through an internet cafe system.  By this, I mean where your browser redirects to an internal web page where you can enter a code.  On the guest, I can successfully connect to the virtual network adapter, but I do not get internet access, nor a redirect to the internal web page.  I use OpenDNS for the host.

I have no problems when connecting through ethernet or regular wifi.

Can someone tell me any of:
1) How to fix the problem.
2) How such cafe systems work.
3) At least point me to a technical explanation of such a cafe system so I can begin to troubleshoot.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you ask the Cafe what specific system they use and then ask us how that system works. There are many vendors of public wifi systems and they are all different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use NAT mode of network transmission, not bridged mode.
2. it is usually based on a proxy suite on the default gateway

Answer (score 0):

The cafe may be restricting the code you used to one IP address.  If your virtual machine is set to bridged then it will acquire it's own IP address which the network sees as a different IP.  Try using NAT mode.